# On shutdown, MAMP sometimes asks me for username and password, but not always

Tags: macos, mamp

When I log onto my Mac OSX admin account, I have MAMP automatically start so I can get right to managing my server content. But every now and then, when I shut down my computer, the MAMP window opens up and asks for my admin name and password, and the shut down process halts until this is entered.

Any reason why it would only ask me in certain cases when I shut down, and not all the time? It's sometimes annoying when you shut down and it shows up when I don't expect it. I don't know what are the conditions for MAMP to ask for your admin info if you request to close the program.

Answer (score 4):

MAMP requires sudo password for shutting down the apache and/or mysql server when ports smaller than 1024 have been configured. on UNIX like systems (like Mac OS) you need "su" privileges to start/stop this IP services.

note: probably when it does not explicitly asks you for a password, you where using it a moment ago for another activity.

Comment: yes UDO you are absolutely right about this. I tried and it worked.
thanx

Comment: My Apache port is set to 8888, and MySQL is 8889 – yet sometimes MAMP asks for administrator password on my standard user account in order to stop the servers (work laptop). It never asks me a password to START the servers, only sometimes will it ask me for the password to STOP the servers. This to me indicates a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences in mamp and click reset mamp ports, it will change the ports to default.

For Apache (8888) [default for MAC OS X]

For MySQL (8889)  [default for MAC OS X]